# NHibernate 3 Linq query caching

Tags: c#, nhibernate, caching

I've just started using LINQ with NHibernate in NHibernate 3, after previously using ICriteria.

Here's an example query:

```
ISession session = NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.GetSession();

var results = from project in session.Query<Project>()
              where project.ProjectState == ProjectState.Archive
              orderby project.ProjectNumber
              select project;

return results.ToList();
```

How do I set that to cache? I've had a look around and other questions seem to use a different (perhaps outdated?) syntax, or perhaps I'm doing it wrong...

Comment: Try "results.Cacheable().ToList();"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `Cacheable()` extension method on your Queryable before calling `ToList()`.

Comment: I don't think there's any official documentation yet... I started updating the existing docs a few months ago, but lost the motivation. I believe it's covered in Jason Dentler's book.