# How do I cache compiled LINQ query (not results)?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, nhibernate, expression-trees

It looks like each time I query something with LINQ NHibernate builds that query from scratch:

[image: dotTrace report]

The code looks like

```
session.Query<User>().Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id)).ToFuture();
```

Is it possible to avoid recompiling it?

Also the same question about caching QueryOver/Criteria queries (not so critical but it may still fit the scope).

Comment: @stybl "reusing LINQ query" and "reusing LINQ to database NH query" are not same things

Comment: I'm aware, which is why I retracted the close vote. Forgot about the comment though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4817010/1162077

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Particularly this case was caused by that the access to ids (`int[]`) here

```
session.Query<User>().Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id)).ToFuture();
```

was transformed into `MemberAccessExpression` (not `ConstantExpression`) and NHibernate had to evaluate it. Though `ids` was never changed it still was captured into a closure generated class (like `DisplayClass<>.ids`).

I optimized this case by making my own version of `PartialEvaluatingExpressionTreeVisitor`:

```
    protected Expression EvaluateSubtree(Expression subtree)
    {
        ArgumentUtility.CheckNotNull(nameof(subtree), subtree);
        var memberExpression = subtree as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression != null)
        {
            Expression constant;
            if (TryEvaluateMember(memberExpression, out constant)) return constant;
        }

        if (subtree.NodeType != ExpressionType.Constant)
            throw new NHibernateExpressionOptimizerException(subtree);
        ConstantExpression constantExpression = (ConstantExpression)subtree;
        IQueryable queryable = constantExpression.Value as IQueryable;
        if (queryable != null && queryable.Expression != constantExpression)
            return queryable.Expression;
        return constantExpression;
    }

    bool TryEvaluateMember(MemberExpression memberExpression, out Expression constant)
    {
        constant = null;
        ConstantExpression c = memberExpression.Expression == null ? Expression.Constant(null) : EvaluateSubtree(memberExpression.Expression) as ConstantExpression;
        if (c == null) return false;
        var fieldInfo = memberExpression.Member as FieldInfo;
        if (fieldInfo != null)
        {
            constant = Expression.Constant(ReflectorReadFieldDelegate(fieldInfo, c.Value));
            return true;
        }

        var propertyInfo = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
        if (propertyInfo != null)
        {
            constant = Expression.Constant(ReflectorReadPropertyDelegate(propertyInfo, c.Value));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The reflector delegates use a kind of cached reflection.emit magic.

Comment: This sounds like changing the default behaviour, which I'm in general not fond of. Why not wrap it in a method call, like public static T ToConst<T>(T item) { return item;}, and then apply your logic for that method call? it gives you more flexibility, and is more clear what is your intention, no?

Answer (score 1):

I recall that expressions with the contains linq method are not compiled because the enumerable could be different in future calls

A possible workaround is to use the ugly way of OR operator if you know that the number of elements is always the same

Another workaround is to call the following method:

session.QueryOver().AndRestrictionOn(x=>x.id).IsIn(ids)